# How to use OSAtomicxxx methods to achieve circular effect

Tags: objective-c, ios, math, atomic, operation

We want to achieve a circular effect by using any of OSAtomic* methods, for example, start the counting from MAX_INT, decrement one every time, and then go back to MAX_INT once reached 0. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Language? Operating system? Framework?

Comment: On many platforms subtracting `1` from an (unsigned) integer with value `0` will wrap-round to `max_int`.  I haven't a clue whether this applies to your situation, but it's worth checking.

Comment: that's indeed what I ended up with.